# Regular Expression Help [firstname].[lastname]+expense@mydomain.com

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regular expression that would match the following:

> firstname.lastname+expense@mydomain.com

- joe.smith+expense@mydomain.com (**match**)
- joesmith@mydomain.com (not matching)
- jsmith+expense@mydomain.com (not matching)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\+expense@mydomain\.com
```

should do it.